# How to subtract width of a div with a randomized number in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a div that is 200px in width, and I want this div to decrease in width by the value of a randomized number in javascript.

Like this:

```
document.getElementById("myGreenHpBar").style.width-randomized number
```

How would I write it exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
var div = document.getElementById("div");

div.style.width = "300px";  

function rand(){
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 1;
    div.style.width = subPx(div.style.width, randNum) + "px";
    alert(randNum);
}

// Gets : "200px", "50"; Returns 200 - 50
function subPx(a, b){
  return parseInt(a, 10) - b;
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/korivemu/1/edit)

#### Explanation for `subPx`

1. At first button click, it receives `300px` (the original width of div element) and a `randNum` (suppose `10`) as `a` and `b` respectively.
2. [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) method converts `300px` to the integer `300` in base `10` (the second argument).
3. From `300`, we subtract `10` (the `b`), and get `290`.
4. Return `290`.
5. Now in the `rand` function, the expression becomes: `div.style.width = 290 + "px"`
6. Since, `"px"` is String, the integer `290` gets coerced to the string `"290"` and we get the result as: `div.style.width = "290px";`

Hope that helps !

Comment: exactly what I wanted, having a hard time understanding the function subPx though :/

Comment: @DuploW I am adding an explanation.

Comment: Thanks, should I also have a, b and a, 10 - b or should I changed it so it fits my own code? cuz now the green bar never actually goes down to 0. Edit: I understand the code better now when I read it again, but I'm still wondering how to make it go down to 0 completely

Comment: @DuploW "cuz now the green bar never actually goes down to 0." [It does.](http://jsbin.com/korivemu/3/edit?output) (Centered the div to show that it actually goes thin and out of sight after some time).

Comment: when my value is at 0, the green bar is sometimes stuck on 20%, 5%, 1% etc. but never actually completely gone. Why does it take like a min for yours to dissapear tho? Seems odd.

Comment: @DuploW It would be hard for me to find the actual cause until I see the code you use. How about a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var width = document.getElementById("myGreenHpBar").style.width;
var new_width = width - random_number;
document.getElementById("myGreenHpBar").style.width = new_width;
```

Comment: I think you mean `width` instead of `a` since you never define a.

Comment: @DuploW are you sure random number generation is ok? Try to use some constant instead of random number for testing.